# Change in UITextView return key types does not display on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ios9

While my textView is being edited with keyboard showing, I am changing the keyboard return key type from "Send" to "Default".

```
textView.returnKeyType = .default
textView.reloadInputViews()
```

This works fine on iOS 10+ but iOS 9 does not display the changed return key.

Comment: Isn't the default "Return" according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireturnkeytype)?

Comment: I have the return key type set to "Send" and now with above code I am trying to change it to the default type "return"

Comment: Ohh, okay, that clears things up a little. So for example if nothing is in textView you want it to be return?

Comment: its not conditional, I want to explicitly change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this after changing the return key type:

```
textView.resignFirstResponder()
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```